# GO SDK for Google Translation api is returning HTML instead of JSON response

Tags: html, go, google-translation-api

I am using following code for translation:

```
import (
    "context"

    "cloud.google.com/go/translate"
    "golang.org/x/text/language"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

func TranslateFromGoogle(sourceArr []string, srcLangCode, trgtLangCode, apiKey string) (targetArr []translate.Translation, err error) {
    src, err := language.Parse(srcLangCode)
    if err != nil {
        return targetArr, err
    }
    trgt, err := language.Parse(trgtLangCode)
    if err != nil {
        return targetArr, err
    }
    ctx := context.Background()
    opts := option.WithAPIKey(apiKey)
    c, err := translate.NewClient(ctx, opts)
    if err != nil {
        return targetArr, err
    }
    defer c.Close()
    targetArr, err = c.Translate(ctx, sourceArr, trgt,
        &translate.Options{
            Source: src,
            Format: translate.Text,
        })
    return targetArr, err
}
```

In the error, following type of data is returned:

```
googleapi: got HTTP response code 400 with body: <!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=en>\n  <meta charset=utf-8>\n  <meta name=viewport content=\"initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width\">\n  <title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title>\n  <style>\n    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}\n  </style>\n  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>\n  <p><b>400.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>\n  <p>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>\n
```

But I want only text from this like:

```
Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.
```

Am I missing something or it is an SDK issue? How can I get the desired message as output?

Comment: HTTP status code 400 means "bad request"—why didn't you bother to look it up? You could save that HTML output (starting with `<!DOCTYPE html>…`) into a file (ending with the ".html") extension and then open it in any browser—by double clicking on that file—to actually read what's there. What prevented you from doing that?

Comment: @kostix  it returns error in this format for every status code like I have received this for code 412 also. I am using this function inside an api so when this function returns error I need to return the message from my api. Opening html in browser does not make any sense in my case.

Comment: The status code tells you pretty much everything you need to know. The error messages don't provide any additional detail.

Comment: in this scenerio, if I pass a large number of strings to be translated but my api key does not support that much characters, then it is returning as bad request. which is not appropriate. It should return a proper message. If I call the google api directly, that is returning the actual message for the problem. I am stuck here now.

Comment: Did you try to use 'response[0].text' as documented on [Translate strings](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/samples/translate-text-with-model) documentation?

Comment: @PjoterS I am talking about error which is returned from sdk not the response. By the way the response is correct by doing 'response[0].text' when there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

The approach should be to parse the error output and just get the desire message from it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings" 
    "bytes"
    
    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

func main() {

    var s []string 
    
    string := "googleapi: got HTTP response code 400 with body: <!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=en>\n  <meta charset=utf-8>\n  <meta name=viewport content=\"initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width\">\n  <title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title>\n  <style>\n    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}\n  </style>\n  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>\n  <p><b>400.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>\n  <p>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>\n"
    doc, err := html.Parse(strings.NewReader(string))
    if err != nil { 
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    
    var f func(*html.Node)
    f = func(n *html.Node) {
        
        if n.Type == html.ElementNode && n.Data == "p" {
            text := &bytes.Buffer{}
            collectText(n, text)
            s = append(s, text.String())
        }
        for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling {
            f(c)
        }
    }
    f(doc)
    
    fmt.Println(s[1]) // return value
}

func collectText(n *html.Node, buf *bytes.Buffer) {
    if n.Type == html.TextNode {
        buf.WriteString(n.Data)
    }
    for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling {
        collectText(c, buf)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  That’s all we know.
```

**Update:** To explain why the above approach should be use you will have to check how 'Translate' function works:

```
func (c *Client) Translate(ctx context.Context, inputs []string, target language.Tag, opts *Options) ([]Translation, error)
```

So, as you can see, it returns a translation type and error type which are:

```
// translation
type Translation struct {
    Text string
    Source language.Tag
    Model string
} 

// error
type error interface {
    Error() string
}
```

See more [here](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/translate@v1.0.0#pkg-functions).

In conclusion, you will have to parse the error string to get the desired output.